# Convexity notion versus local pathwise connectedness

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, topological-vector-spaces, locally-convex-spaces

Let $X$ be a topological vector space. Let us call a set $S\subset X$ *almost-convex* if, for every $x,y\in S$ and every $V$ a neighborhood of zero, there exists a continuous path from $x$ to $y$ entirely contained in $([x,y]+V)\cap S$, where $[x,y]$ denotes the segment with end-points $x,y$. (In other words the path in $S$ is close to the segment.)

How does this notion relate to (local) pathwise connectedness?

I can prove that if $S$ is almost-convex then $S$ is pathwise connected and locally pathwise connected while $\overline{S}$(the closure of $S$) is convex and, clearly, every convex set is almost-convex.

I am interested in a converse of the form: if $S$ is locally pathwise connected with  $\overline{S}$ convex then $S$ is almost-convex.

Comment: Do you assume that $X$ is Hausdorff?

Comment: @PaulFrost You can assume Hausdorff separation.